# Почему IEnumerable<> остаётся пустым?

Tags: c#

Почему apps2 остаётся пустым?

```
IEnumerable<AppFile> apps2 = Enumerable.Empty<AppFile>();

var a2 = new AppFile();

a2.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"c:\ConsoleApp1.exe");
a2.Path = GetTargetPath(@"c:\ConsoleApp1.exe");


apps2 = Enumerable.Empty<AppFile>();
var af2 = new List<AppFile>() { a2 }; //здесь af2 не пустой
apps2.Concat(af2);
```

Comment: потому что concat не меняет исходную последовательность. Он возвращает новую

Comment: `apps2 = apps2.Concat(af2);`

Comment: @Grundy, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @D.Stark, ответы в ответы.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Concat` возвращает новую последовательность, а не изменяет прежнюю (как и все операции `Linq`), поэтому вам необходимо явно сохранить результат:

```
apps2 = apps2.Concat(af2);
```